# Tk window not appearing

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am writing a basic script that moves a red square around a 500x500 window in random directions. However, the window does not appear when I run the code and no error message is displayed.

I've tried using both wish and terminal to run the code but neither work.

FYI: `pass` is my do nothing function

my code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

proc pass {} {}

proc rand { min max } {
    set maxFactor [expr [expr $max + 1] - $min]
    set value [expr int([expr rand() * 100])]
    set value [expr [expr $value % $maxFactor] + $min]
return $value
}

package require Img

wm geometry . 500x500
wm title . "move"

. configure -background "#333"

set x "250"
set y "250"

image create photo img1 -file "square.png"
label .l -image img1
place .l -x $x -y $y


while {"3" eq "3"} {
    set command [rand 1 4]
    if {$command eq 1} {
        eval "if {$y ne 5} {\nincr y -5\nplace .l -x $x -y $y\n}"
    } elseif {$command eq 2} {
        eval "if {$y ne 475} {\nincr y 5\nplace .l -x $x -y $y\n}"
    } elseif {$command eq 3} {
        eval "if {$x ne 5} {\nincr x -5\nplace .l -x $x -y $y\n}"
    } elseif {$command eq 4} {
        eval "if {$x ne 475} {\nincr x 5\nplace .l -x $x -y $y\n}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way anything works in a GUI is through a steady stream of events. Button clicks, scrolling, and even requests from the operating system to redraw the window are all events. Without being able to process these events, the GUI is either frozen or never appears.

Because of your infinite loop, these events are never processed. Thus, even the initial "draw yourself on the screen" event goes completely ignored.

Event-based programming is not the same as writing non-event-based programming. You can't just expect the code to run once from top to bottom. Instead, you must set up your GUI to properly generate and respond to events.

If you want to move the square around in random direction, the proper way to do that is to create a function that moves it once, and then arrange for that function to be called every so often. You do that last part -- running a function in the future -- with the [after](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/after.htm) command. This lets you put an event on the event queue which instructs the program to run your function.

**Example**

To simplify the example, the following code will just move the label to a random location rather than use the convoluted logic of your original code. You can later modify the function to use your existing logic if you want. I want to remove as much complexity as possible so that you can understand the technique.

First, start with the function to move the label once:

```
proc move_label {} {
    set x [rand 0 500]
    set y [rand 0 500]
    place .l -x $x -y $y
}
```

Next, create a function that calls this function, and then arranges for itself to be called again using `after`:

```
proc animate {} {
    move_label
    after 1000 animate
}
```

Finally, call this function once after you create the label and it will run every second until your program exits.

```
label .l -image img1
animate
```

By having the `animate` function call `after` on itself, you end up with a never-ending loop that runs approximately once per second. In-between iterations of the loop tcl is free to process all other events that allow the GUI to continue to respond to user and OS events.

Note: you need to run this with `wish` rather than `tclsh`, since `wish` includes the tk commands, and it will automatically start the event loop for you.

Comment: You can put `package require Tk` at the top and have `tclsh` work just like `wish`; this is recommended. The main differences between the two these days are 1) that default `package require Tk` and 2) how, on Windows, `wish` is built to be a GUI application instead of a console application.